# Changing SPeech Recognition to spanish in windows 10 iot

Tags: windows-10

I´m trying to use SpeechRecognition in windows 10 iot RPi3. It recognize commands in English, but now my goal is to make it recognize commands in Spanish. I'm using UWP and actually it executes commands in Spanish in my laptotp, but when I change the language to Spanish in the RPI it doesn´t recognize it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify you have both keyboard layouts and language packs installed?